# Take automated Screenshot

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to take automated screenshots of a android device every 10 seconds and then save them into a directory.
I used this method but it doesn't work
who can help me please!!!

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p /mnt/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
try {
    sh.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is this for an app? or for testing purposes? or other?

Comment: What does not work? Do you get any errors? In case the screenshot part does not work, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the library I didn't check It but title seems helpful
https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library
and want to thanks @**still_learning**

This is how we can take screenshot using adb tool 
http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/grab-android-screenshot-to-computer-via.html

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen.png
```

Extra efforts:
You need to do some programming.

For Windows:
Make a .bat file or .cmd file that will execute at every 10 second and contains above code.
for execution in every 10 second set the system scheduler.

For Linux :
Make .sh file or .py file that contains above code (systax might be change in linux) and you need to find "how to schedule program execution in linux?".

Comment: [yasso](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2706936/) wants to capture the screen using Android code (running **on** the device).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-take-screen-shots-in-java-taking-screenshots-java/

Comment: The comments below your answer are not supposed to provide links to duplicate questions. And - whether you know it or not - Android does not provide any AWT classes (referring to your second link).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/

Comment: Okay, okay, you've pasted enough links. *Perhaps* you should add them to the answer instead of posting more and more comments.